# How to figure out that two apps are on the same device on macOS(Alternative of identifierForVendor in macOS)

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

[advertisingIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier) is different for apps from the same vendor.

Of course there is an ability to add apps into group and share some "unique string". But I suppose that there must be some easier way.

I also read about "[Uniquely Identifying a Macintosh Computer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn1103/_index.html)" but I suppose that such apps are rejected in mac AppStore.

Answer (score 3):

In our app we access the system serial number. We use it to try prevent multiple users using the same account + for debug purposes (so not for ads or anything, our app has none).

We also have code to access the hardware uuid but that code isn't actually used at the moment, but it is in there, so not sure how deep Apple checks. So you might be able to use this one too. As an additional step you could hash either of these (or hash them appended or something).

This app has been on the AppStore for a long while now, and was never rejected for this reason. So I'd say accessing this data on macOS should be ok (for now) depending on usage and safe to submit to the app store.

Keep in mind that in some rare cases, the serial number will not be available. In that case we store a random string in UserDefaults.standard and use that cached value in the future.

Since this information won't be available to your 'other' app(s), this workaround won't work for you though.